# Pods are grayed out in Target -> Linked Frameworks

Tags: xcode, frameworks

Problems with pods and frameworks not being found seem to be numerous on Stackoverflow and I have read many threads and tried many things (probably to the point of really messing up my project.) But I'm pretty sure that the grayed out framework means Xcode can't find the files and that is probably because a path variable isn't pointing Xcode to the correct directory. There seem to be many path variables to set and they can be set to search recursively and/or they can be $(inherited) from somewhere else. (This $(inherited) thing is also some kind of flag that pod update seems to complain about now and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do something about that.) So, could someone tell me exactly which path variable points Xcode to the pod frameworks?

Comment: I was working with the Facebook SDK pods and frameworks and it turns out that version 4.39 doesn't work and you need to down grade in your pod file to 4.36 like this:
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit','4.36.0'

Comment: And I'm not convinced that did so I just started a whole new project from scratch, copied code where I could and redid the GUI stuff in Xcode.